# Using DataFactory to copy documents from one container to another and adding a partition key value in the document

Tags: azure-data-factory

My job is to move data from my container in CosmosDb to another container in same database. In my new Database I have defined my partition key as **/PKey** but the document to be moved does not have a key named as "PKey". I would like to create this key while moving the document to new container and this PKey will contain value by concanating few of my key values in the document(for e.g. PKey:"will be combination of Id and name key in the document").

So if my Source is : `{Name: "ZZZ", ID: 21}` My target will be `{Name: "ZZZ", ID: 21, PKey: "ZZZ21"}`

I would like to know if this possible in Data factory which I have selected for this copy activity , i.e. if I can create a Key on the fly while moving documents.Thanks

Comment: Which database have you used, Azure Cosmos db (SQL api) or Azure Cosmos db (Mongodb api) ?

Comment: Its Cosmos Db SQL Api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat(Name,toString(ID))` expression for derived column.

Detail steps are given below

**Step1:** Create a Dataflow

[image]

**Step2:** Create a 1. `Source`, 2. `Derive Column` and 3. `Sink Destination` within Dataflow as shown in below image

[image]

**Step3:** Add source dataset in `Source1`

[image]

**Step4:** In `Derived Column` create `new column` as shown in below image
Use `concat(Name,toString(ID))` expression to create `PKey` partitioned column

[image]

**Step5:** You will get following Output

[image]

**Step6:** Add sink dataset to Output dataset.
Now you can run dataflow.

[image]